# Automate Windows installation for large companies

Tags: windows, active-directory, wds, wadk

So I am not an expert (System Engineer Apprentice) but I am looking for a way to automate the windows-installation process on a large scale. In my company I have to setup a lot of computers and it is very time-consuming.

We are working with a predefined Windows-Image (Windows ADK) from an USB. But in the setup process I have to manually type in the Hostname for the computer and manually choose the Operating System.

Now I have the idea to use something like Windows Deployment Services to enable network-based installation, so I don't need to use the USB anymore.

But there is one more thing:
**Is there a way the Active Directory automatically assigns a hostname to the computer which is defined by a naming convention. Or can I use WDS to do this?**

Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: Use the unattend.xml to end to end automate with WDS. Use something like MDT to avoid golden images. MDT also integrates into WDS. MDT also has support for the WDS multicasting.

Answer (score 2):

WDS has the option of using what's referred to as the "[Machine Naming Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wdsosd/72aea052-00d3-41d5-9292-43dd6884b238)" to auto-generate unique hostnames for newly deployed Windows machines.